# Why file path now getting concatenate in variable

Tags: string, powershell, search, pattern-matching

I am writing powershell script to find few string in a path. It returns file path correctly in variable. Now if I try to add it to some other variable it adds empty (adds nothing), but if I print variable separately it gets print correctly.

My code,

```
$final = ""
foreach($e in $stringIDColum)
{ 

$e
$var = (Get-ChildItem “C:\path” -recurse -exclude $excluded | Select-String -pattern $e | group path | select  name)

$final += "," + $e + "," + $var
}
```

Here value of `$e` is getting added, `$var` is not getting added. But if I print `$var` separately it prints path correctly.

Secondly I have tried various ways, to print line number, but it does not print line number in front of path.

Comment: Can you give an example of `$stringIDColum`?

Comment: Its an array, and I am assigning values as, `$stringIDColum += $worksheet.cells.Item($i, $FixedColumn).text`

Comment: Is `“C:\path”` normal? see the quotes used, you should use `"` quotes

Comment: @MickyBalladelli I don't why it is pasted that way. But I have used correct quotes. Also getting output in variable.

Comment: I think the issue is that $var is potentially an array. So you need to convert it a string. Check the type once it's created.

Comment: @MickyBalladelli You saved my day.. please post as answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that $var is potentially an array. So you need to convert it a string. Check the type once it's created.